# Почему не работает обращение к style?

Tags: javascript

```js
function next(){
    var slider = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
    var count = slider.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < slider.length; i++){
      if(slider[i].style.zIndex === "10"){
        slider[i].style.zIndex = 1;
      }
  }
}
```

Вот этот код работает нормально. Но если я пропишу
slider[i + 1].style.zIndex = 10;

То есть у следующего элемента установить zIndex = 10, выскакивает ошибка? подскажите почему?

Answer (score 3):

> Но если я пропишу slider[i + 1].style.zIndex = 10;
>
> То выскакивает
>   ошибка? подскажите почему?

Потому что если например элементов у массива 10, а начинаются с нуля, то что делать в случае когда `i` дойдет до края и будет равен 9, то есть будет  `slider[9 + 1]` ? Нет такого элемента с таким индексом

Comment: Наверное хотели написать в ответе `slider[9 + 1]`

Comment: Я уже запутался. Как мне прописать что бы следующий элемент изменил свой индекс на 10?

Comment: @Sinevik наверное `slider.length - 1`